# Compilation error in arduino IDE while integrating with DHT11 sensor

Tags: windows-10, arduino, sensors

I have added the `DHT11` library already but I am still getting this below mentioned error while compiling. Kindly help me to fix this. Thank you in advance

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"In file included from C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\libraries\DHT_sensor_library\DHT_U.cpp:15:0:
C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\libraries\DHT_sensor_library\DHT_U.h:36:29: fatal error: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno. This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
?
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need 'Adafruit Unified Sensor' library. Search for it in the library manager and install. You should be good to go.